# How to create library of HTML snippets to use in posts

Tags: blog

I have a requirement to allow our WordPress blog authors to be able to **run a specific HTML advert** at the bottom of each blog article **from a choice of several pre-created** HTML adverts.

Once the post article is published, this HTML advert will appear on the public page.

We want it to be straight forwards as possible to create further HTML adverts which would then be added to the list of available choices.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: This is quite broad and open to _multiple_ takes on it. What had you tried or considered? What didn't work or fit for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to achieve this. like a button on click of it, you can append in the article textbox or input. like

```
    $('#boldbutton').on('click',function(){
$('#textid').append('<b></b>');
});
```

Like above you can create as many as button you like to have.